# How to impute nan values in a Pandas dataframe from a multi-index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, 20, 4],
                   [3, 1, np.nan, 1],
                   [3, 1, 15, 1],
                   [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1],
                   [10, 1, 30, 4],
                   [50, 2, 35, 4],
                   [10, 1, 37, 4],
                   [40, 2, 30, 1]],
                  columns=list("ABCD"))
```

I want to fill the Nan values with their group means.
Towards that purpose, I run the following:

```
df_mean=df.groupby(["B","D"]).mean()
df_mean

        A     C
B   D       
1   1   3.0   15.0
    4   10.0  33.5
2   1   40.0  30.0
    4   50.0  27.5
```

Is there a way to fill the dataframe df with the values computed in df_mean?

One way to do this would be as in [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/107028/51858)

```
df[["A", "C"]] = (
    df
    # create groups
    .groupby(["B", "D"])
    # transform the groups by filling na values with the group mean
    .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
)
```

However, for a few millions of rows, where the simple groupby([...]).mean() would take a few seconds, take too long...

It there a quicker way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) by `mean` and pass to [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df.fillna(df.groupby(["B", "D"]).transform('mean'))
print (df)
      A  B     C  D
0  50.0  2  20.0  4
1   3.0  1  15.0  1
2   3.0  1  15.0  1
3   3.0  1  15.0  1
4  10.0  1  30.0  4
5  50.0  2  35.0  4
6  10.0  1  37.0  4
7  40.0  2  30.0  1
```

Your solution with aggregation is possible also use this way:

```
df = df.fillna(df[['B','D']].join(df.groupby(["B","D"]).mean(), on=['B','D']))
print (df)
      A  B     C  D
0  50.0  2  20.0  4
1   3.0  1  15.0  1
2   3.0  1  15.0  1
3   3.0  1  15.0  1
4  10.0  1  30.0  4
5  50.0  2  35.0  4
6  10.0  1  37.0  4
7  40.0  2  30.0  1
```

Comment: By the way, it seems that transform('mean') (similarly .mean() in the groupby) when encountering a NaN value, simply return a NaN. Is there a way to instead only consider non NaN values when computing the mean? I've tried using np.nanmean instead of 'mean', but I still get NaN. Am I doing sth wrong, or does this mean that I simply don't have data for that group?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. - hmmm, in pandas `mean` drop `NaN`s. So if in ouput `NaN` it means per group, column only NaNs values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combine_first`:

```
out = df.combine_first(df.groupby(['B', 'D']).transform('mean'))
print(out)

# Output
      A  B     C  D
0  50.0  2  20.0  4
1   3.0  1  15.0  1
2   3.0  1  15.0  1
3   3.0  1  15.0  1
4  10.0  1  30.0  4
5  50.0  2  35.0  4
6  10.0  1  37.0  4
7  40.0  2  30.0  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I gave you sth.... I'm going to accept Jez's answer since it was the first to work for me. ;)

Comment: Not a problem :) The important thing is you have a solution that works